# Combining two graphs created by Block, (each have several plots) in Show with respective legends

Tags: plotting

I want to combine two graphs using `Show`. It sounds pretty straightforward but it actually does not meet my requirements in the way below..

I have two graphs `plot1` and `plot2` which use `Block`.

In `plot1`, all plots should be created with `straight lines`.

In `plot2` all plots should be created with `dashed lines`.

I therefore can understand and distinguish them once I look at the combination produced by `Show`.

My actual code is long so I just paste a simple representer example here:

```
heightSmall[t_]:= M*t/(g+t)

plot1 = Block[{M = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, g = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, 
  Plot[Evaluate[heightSmall[t]], {t, 0, 0.1}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"M, g = 0 Small", "M, g = 0.1 Small", "M, g = 0.2 Small", 
     "M, g = 0.3 Small"}]]

heightAsymptotic[t_]:=M*t/(g+0.001*t)

plot2 = Block[{M = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, g = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, 
      Plot[Evaluate[heightAsymptotic[t]], {t, 0, 0.1}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}, 
       PlotLegends -> {"M, g = 0 Asymptotic", "M, g = 0.1 Asymptotic", "M, g = 0.2 Asymptotic", "M, g = 0.3 Asymptotic"}]]

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

1) How can I put legends inside each plot and eventually `Show` (In `Show` there should be just one legend block stating `straight lines` and `dashed lines` for respective plots).

2) In the final plot produced by `Show` each colour should represent relative heightSmall[t] and heightAsymptotic[t] with `straight` and `dashed lines` respectively. I tried but it did not work properly.

3) I do not understand why `OverHat[g]` in `PlotLegends` does not produce OverHat of g. 
I might need to post another question about this.

I do not know is it doable or not. Hopefully, it is.

Comment: You can get dashed lines with `PlotStyle -> ({Dashed, #} & /@ {Red, Green, Blue, Black})`

Comment: I can add an overhat inside a string with the key sequence `g, Ctrl+7, ^`.  This shows up in the legend

Comment: Great! Now my two problems have already solved. Thanks @mikado. How about the problem in 1)  ?

Comment: You can produce both sets of curves in a single plot.  For example, using `Evaluate[{heightSmall[t], heightAsymptotic[t]}]`.  This should let you specify a single list of legend strings.

Comment: But when I evaluate both, I get:  `Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {t,0,0.1}) beyond position 2 in Plot[{0.24 +0.16 t^2,0.24 +0.113284 t^2,0.24 -0.198874 t^2,0.24 -4.53683 t^2},<<4>>,PlotLegends->{M, Overscript[g, ^] = 0,M, Overscript[g, ^] = 0.1,M, Overscript[g, ^] = 1,M, Overscript[g, ^] = 10}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.` all the data it uses is fine as far as I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following illustrates most of the features you request

```
Block[{M = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, g = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[{heightSmall[t], heightAsymptotic[t]}], {t, 0, 0.1}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Join[{Red, Green, Blue, 
     Black}, ({Dashed, #} & /@ {Red, Green, Blue, Black})], 
  PlotLegends -> {"M, g = 0 Small", "M, g = 0.1 Small", 
    "M, g = 0.2 Small", "M, g = 0.3 Small", "M, g = 0 Asymptotic", 
    "M, g = 0.1 Asymptotic", "M, g = 0.2 Asymptotic", 
    "M, g = 0.3 Asymptotic"}]]
```

[image]

You can add an overhat inside a string with the key sequence <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+7</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>. This shows up in the legend.  (I haven't shown this because it makes a mess of the code I've pasted in).

Comment: Great @mikado, thanks so much. So is there any way not to repeat the colour in the legend. Or alternatively, is there any way to have two list of legends showing the results from different functions namely heightSmall[] and heightAsymptotic[] ?      And another point, the legend is not shown in the output after saving the plot.